# autoload_paths change naming convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a problem with naming convention that Rails uses for loading the files of their `config.autoload_paths`.

I'm building an application that uses some set of gems.

This set of gems are supposed to be extended by the application in the way that, if a model `User` is defined inside the gem, then if the application wants to extend that model you will have to create a file named `"app/models/_user.rb"`, and inside that file you will write something like:

```
# Extending gems user model in the application level
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def new_method_that_make_sense_for_my_app
    #supercode here... bla bla
  end
end
```

So, given that scenario, let's assume that this will not change. So, I will have to add this kind of files to the `config.autoload_paths` array, so I can make changes to my code and apply them without having to restart the server (in development env).

Here's the problem:

If I add the following code to my application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/_user.rb)
```

Rails won't autoload this file on each request, because the autoload_paths elements rely on the convention that the **name** of the file is equivalent to the name of the **class** defined in that file.

So, resuming: the **underscore** in `"_user.rb"` file name is messing everything up!

Is there a way to configure Rails so I can tell it to search also for files starting with an underscore and followed by the name of the class?

Thanks!